# Sub-Consulta SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy nuevo por estos lados.

Estoy haciendo un consulta SQL, la cual empezó siendo chica y termino complicandome la vida.

Tengo algo Así:
Dos tablas.
Una tiene datos de costos, fecha y ID, la otra tiene fecha y tipo de cambio/Moneda.

Dentro del select principal, tengo que tomar el costo y dividirlo por el tipo de cambio, con la fecha donde se hizo el registro.

```
SELECT Nro_id, fecha, 
costo $, 
(costo/ Select top 1(cambio) from tabla2 LEFT JOIN 
tabla1.fecha=tabla2.fecha) 'Costo U$'
FROM tabla1
```

El problema que tengo es que la subconsulta me trae el primer tipo de cambio y no el de la fecha.

¿Me podrian dar una mano?
Dejo la estructura de las dos tablas.

tabla 1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OT_Control](
    [ID_Nro] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OT_Nro] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Completed_Date] [date] NULL, (Fecha para comparar)
    [Partial_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Employee] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Contractor] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Position] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](120) NULL,
    [Equipment] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Planned_Hours] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Actual_Hours] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Cost] [float] NULL, (Lo que deberia dividir por el cambio de tabla2)
    [Details] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Clasificación_OT] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Nro_Obra] [int] NULL,
    [Tipo_Servicio] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Nro_RQ] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Asset_Number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Alias] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Nro_IR] [int] NULL,
    [Item_IR] [int] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Fech_created] [datetime] NULL,
    [Fech_update] [datetime] NULL,
    [user_edit] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [MoID] [int] NULL,
    [Clasificacion_Tarea] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OT_Control] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_Nro] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Tabla 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[exchangeRateHistory](
    [exId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [exMoneyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [exRate] [money] NULL,
    [exRateSales] [money] NULL,
    [exMoneyOriginalId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [exDate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [exDateLoad] [int] NULL,
    [exHour] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [exUser] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_exchangeRateHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [exId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la estructura de las tablas para verlo con más claridad?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea esta.. pero no del todo..

Para empezar, escribamos la consulta correcta:

```
SELECT 
    Nro_id, 
    fecha, 
    costo AS '$', 
    (costo / 
        (Select cambio from tabla2 WHERE tabla1.fecha=tabla2.fecha)) AS 'Costo U$'
FROM 
    tabla1
```

Y ahora.. veamos el porque.. la idea la tenias, tenias que traer un registro de la tabla2.. pero, tu forma de traerlo fue ambigua.

En general para hacer estas cosas, recomiendo hacer siempre el query por pedazos. Vos ni siquiera sabias que devolvia esto:

```
Select top 1(cambio) from tabla2 LEFT JOIN 
tabla1.fecha=tabla2.fecha
```

Porque si hubieras sabido, sabrias que lo que hace eso, es mezclar las dos tablas uniendolas por fecha, y luego devolverte el primer registro. Que es cualquiera que hubiera encontrado.

Entonces lo que en realidad querias era:

```
Select cambio from tabla2 WHERE tabla1.fecha=tabla2.fecha
```

siempre tomando en cuenta, que si fuera de prueba, hubieras igualado tabla2.fecha a cualquier fecha ;)

Comment: Muchas Gracias... Habia dos temas. Uno era ese de la fecha y el otro era un error mio, que estoy haciendo la suma del costo y me habia olvidado el SUM, por ende siempre me dio la mitad. Muchas Gracias Igual